# Checking if a Key/Value pair exists in an Array of Objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the oldest person in an array of objects. In the below example, my final answer should return 'Carly' because she has been alive for the longest.

My code is returning Ray because it doesn't recognise that Carly is still Alive.

I have tried nesting my code in an if/else statement which checks to see if the yearOfDeath value exists but clearly something is wrong as it is still returning the Ray object.

```
let findTheOldest = function(arr) {
    var oldest = 0;
    var oldestPerson = {};
    var today = new Date();
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();


    arr.reduce((total, person) => {

      if (person.yearOfDeath){
         if ((person.yearOfDeath - person.yearOfBirth) > oldest){
            oldest = person.yearOfDeath - person.yearOfBirth;
            oldestPerson = person;
           } 
      } 

      else {
         person.yearOfDeath = yyyy;
         if ((person.yearOfDeath - person.yearOfBirth) > oldest){
            oldest = person.yearOfDeath - person.yearOfBirth;
            oldestPerson = person;
           }
      }

   });

     console.table(oldestPerson);
     console.table(arr);
}



const people = [
      {
        name: 'Carly',
        yearOfBirth: 1066,
      },
      {
        name: 'Ray',
        yearOfBirth: 1962,
        yearOfDeath: 2011
      },
      {
        name: 'Jane',
        yearOfBirth: 1912,
        yearOfDeath: 1941
      },
    ];

findTheOldest(people);
```

Appreciate any help?.

Comment: Why do you _"kill"_ living persons (`person.yearOfDeath = yyyy;`)? o.O

Comment: I am giving them a yearOfDeath for the purposes of calculating how old there, so I can then compare this to all the other people.

Comment: Then just do this at the top of the `.reduce()` call (which btw. is not the correct function to use in this case. Use `.forEach()` or `.sort()`) so you don't have to duplicate the logic.

Comment: Thanks, I'll review my code with your suggestions. I opted for 'reduce' because the JavaScript exercise I was set suggested that function

Comment: `.reduce()` works also but you're using it incorrectly. The callback is supposed to return a value because `.reduce()` also returns a value.

Comment: Don't fully understand that but I'll check out reduce() on MDN

Comment: It should be something like: `const oldestPerson = arr.reduce((resultPerson, currentPerson) => { /* compare resultPerson with current Person */; return /* older person */; }`

Comment: Makes a bit more sense. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `reduce` by a `for` loop, this works. Not sure why you needed `reduce` call there.

```js
let findTheOldest = function(arr) {
    var oldest = 0;
    var oldestPerson = {};
    var today = new Date();
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    for (let i in arr) {
       const person = arr[i];
       if (person.yearOfDeath){
           if ((person.yearOfDeath - person.yearOfBirth) > oldest){
              oldest = person.yearOfDeath - person.yearOfBirth;
              oldestPerson = person;
             } 
        } 

        else {
           person.yearOfDeath = yyyy;
           if ((person.yearOfDeath - person.yearOfBirth) > oldest){
              oldest = person.yearOfDeath - person.yearOfBirth;
              oldestPerson = person;
             }
        }
    }
    
    return oldestPerson;
}



const people = [
      {
        name: 'Carly',
        yearOfBirth: 1066,
      },
      {
        name: 'Ray',
        yearOfBirth: 1962,
        yearOfDeath: 2011
      },
      {
        name: 'Jane',
        yearOfBirth: 1912,
        yearOfDeath: 1941
      },
    ];

const oldest = findTheOldest(people);

console.log(oldest); // shows {name: "Carly", yearOfBirth: 1066}
```

Take into account you're modifying the original array elements (setting `yearOfDeath`). In case you want to avoid that, compare directly to the full year when the person is alive, instead of setting it first to the object.

Improving the code a little bit, that's what I do there:

`if ((person.yearOfDeath || currentYear) - person.yearOfBirth > oldest)` --> in case `yearOfDeath` is `undefined`, current year will be used to compare.

I also applied `reduce` to iterate through all the elements, given you say it was actually required. I used an object with two accumulators there. Also, check you need to initialize it as well.

```js
let findTheOldest = function(arr) {
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    const result = arr.reduce(({ oldest, oldestPerson }, person) => {
       if ((person.yearOfDeath || currentYear) - person.yearOfBirth > oldest)         {
          oldest = (person.yearOfDeath || currentYear) - person.yearOfBirth;
          oldestPerson = person;
        }
        
        return { oldest, oldestPerson };

    }, { oldest: 0, oldestPerson: {} });
    
    return result.oldestPerson;
}



const people = [
      {
        name: 'Carly',
        yearOfBirth: 1066,
      },
      {
        name: 'Ray',
        yearOfBirth: 1962,
        yearOfDeath: 2011
      },
      {
        name: 'Jane',
        yearOfBirth: 1912,
        yearOfDeath: 1941
      },
    ];

const oldest = findTheOldest(people);

console.log(oldest); // shows {name: "Carly", yearOfBirth: 1066}
```

Comment: Thanks. I opted for 'reduce' because the JavaScript exercise I was set suggested that function. Looks like that is a mistake.

Comment: @Christian please check my last update in the second example. I applied `reduce` there, although it doesn't seem to be the most natural approach, but given that you loop through all the items, it's something possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it like this:

```js
const people = [
      {
        name: 'Carly',
        yearOfBirth: 1066,
      },
      {
        name: 'Ray',
        yearOfBirth: 1962,
        yearOfDeath: 2011
      },
      {
        name: 'Jane',
        yearOfBirth: 1912,
        yearOfDeath: 1941
      },
];

function findOldest(arr){
   let ages = people.map(el => {
      let age = el.yearOfDeath == undefined ? new Date().getFullYear() - el.yearOfBirth : el.yearOfDeath - el.yearOfBirth;
      return age;
   })
   let maxAge = Math.max(...ages);
   let index = ages.indexOf(maxAge);
   return arr[index];
}

console.log(findOldest(people));
```

Answer (score 1):

Best to use `.sort()` instead of `.reduce()` here. Sort by `yearOfDeath - yearOfBirth` in descending order and return the first element of the sorted array:

```
let findTheOldest = function(arr) {
  var oldest = 0;
  var oldestPerson = [];
  var today = new Date();
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();


  oldestPerson = arr.sort((personA, personB) => {
    if (personA.yearOfDeath && personB.yearOfDeath) {
      return (personA.yearOfDeath - personA.yearOfBirth) < (personB.yearOfDeath - personB.yearOfBirth) ? 1 : -1;
      }
    else {
    if (!personA.yearOfDeath) personA.yearOfDeath = yyyy;
    if (!personB.yearOfDeath) personB.yearOfDeath = yyyy;
    return (personA.yearOfDeath - personA.yearOfBirth) < (personB.yearOfDeath - personB.yearOfBirth) ? 1 : -1;
    }
  })[0];

  console.log(oldestPerson); //logs the Carly object
  console.log(oldestPerson.name); //logs "Carly"

}
```